# Null pointer exception when proving min heap in a binary tree

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, binary-tree, min-heap

This code is to find out if the binary tree is min heap or not, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at the 3rd if statement in public static boolean isMinHeap, I am unsure as to why I keep getting this exception since I thought the code would be valid due to the above break.

```
public class ArrayHeapChecker {
public static boolean isBinaryTree(Integer[] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] != null && array [(i-1)/ 2] == null)   {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public static boolean isCompleteBinaryTree(Integer[] array) {
    if(!isBinaryTree(array)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)  {
        if ((i % 2 == 0) && array[i] == null && array[i + 1] != null)   {
            return false;
        }
        if ((i % 2 != 0) && array[i] == null && array[i + 1] != null)   {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
public static boolean isMinHeap(Integer[] array) {
    if(!isCompleteBinaryTree(array)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)  {
        if (array[i] == null)   {
            break;
        }
        if (array.length <= ((2*i) + 2))    {
            break;
        }
        if (array[(i * 2) + 1] == null || array[(i * 2) + 2] == null)   {
            break;
        }
        if (array[i] > array[(i * 2) + 1] || array[i] > array[(i * 2) + 2]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you pass for the array? Could it be `null` by any chance?

Comment: i added the full code, if that helps

Comment: isn't `array[(i * 2) + 1` out of bounds ?

Comment: @dazito - That won't cause a NullPointerException

Comment: @Ryota - which is the "3rd if statement"?

Comment: Well have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @dazito yes it is but with the above code, I believe it would be fine.

Comment: @StephenC sorry, I meant the 3rd if statement in the last method (isMinHeap)

Comment: Could you post your log output?

Comment: @acm I have some of the stacktrace if it helps

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ArrayHeapChecker.isMinHeap(ArrayHeapChecker.java:36)
 at TestArrayHeapChecker.testisMinHeap_ArraySizeSeven(TestArrayHeapChecker.java:188)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I believe so, It's homework that is submitted into an automatic program and I believe the automated program acts as a debugger

Comment: If the array passed to `isMinHeap` doesn't have every element filled in, that may be the cause of the NPE...

Comment: @KevinAnderson That shouldn't be the case because the code in the 2nd method ensures that it is a complete binary tree.

Comment: @Ryota - I think that you will find that Kevin is correct.  A non-null entry in the array is the only way that you can get an NPE in that if statement.  Check the logic of the `isBinaryTree` and `isCompleteBinaryTree` methods carefully.  Then check the logic of the `if` statement where the NPE is happening.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for your advice! I added simple if statements in my MinHeap method to check for null values and it now works!

Comment: @KevinAnderson You were right, my assumption that a complete binary tree would only contain values that weren't null was false. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Your are not checking that elements in your `array` are not `null`. You are only checking the following `array[i] != null && array [(i-1)/ 2] == null` in `ArrayHeapChecker#isBinaryTree`. Which does not protect you from a NPE when comparing an `Integer` to `null`. E.g. your code will fail for the following input: `new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null}`. I don't suggest you a fix because it depends on your requirements but your check is not strict enough.

To be more precise, as it is right now, your code will fail whenever you have an `array` with odd length which last element is `null`, except when `lenght == 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the visual stimulus gave me an idea and it worked! I added simple if statements to check for null values and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it help. Anyway, you should consider refactoring because so many `return` clauses nested in `if` and `for` statements are making your code really hard to understand. Ah! you should not edit your question to include the answer, if people read as it is in your edit won't understand the actual question in the first place.